# Dynamically increasing or decreasing percentage using parameter action in tableau

Tags: data-visualization, tableau-api, business-intelligence

I’m stuck with a calculation here I created a parameter action I’ll like users to be able to adjust price for example a parameter where users change the percentage using the parameter  they’ll see how much we could potentially make so basically I need a calculated field that dynamically changing price increase or decrease ,how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a case for a parameter, not a parameter action. Create a parameter with Integer data type, which the users can change, and build a calculated field from that.

Assuming you have a field called [Price], create a calculation such as:

```
SUM([Price])*(1+([IntegerParameter]/100))
```

Note this isn't tested so please check it.

Comment: Thank you ,I’ll try it out I have created the parameter I just need to create the calculation that works with the parameter for users to use the slider to see how much we will potentially make by increasing or readying the parameter percentages